# Pass parameters to function through an action

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic, actions

I'm trying to pass the value of a variable into do_action and then use it in the resulting function but it's not working. The action is being fired in the woocommerce checkout, so it also passes the $checkout variable as well, which is working fine. Simplified example below:

```
add_action( 'my_action', 'my_function' );
function my_function( $checkout, $myvar ) {
  var_dump ($checkout); //Works fine
  var_dump ($myvar); //Returns NULL
}
```

And then calling the action in the template like so:

```
$myvar = 1;
do_action( 'my_action', $checkout, $myvar );
```

I can't access $myvar at all in the function, any help appreciated.

Comment: Do not simplify the question, please. It becomes useless as there is no `my_action` action in WordPress so it's impossible to check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[add_action()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) and [add_filter()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) take 4 params: `string $tag, callable $function_to_add, int $priority = 10, int $accepted_args = 1`.

So, the function you are hooking to takes more than 1 param, then just pass the number of params it accepts as the 4th param to `add_action()`.  In your case,

```
add_action ('my_action', 'my_function', 10, 2) ;
```

Comment: @LewisDonovan: my pleasure